# Use a Plugin (VeeValidate) in Store.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm working with Vuex and added vee-validate ([found here](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/)). I'm using a store object and from one of its actions, I want to be able to add custom errors to the errors collection based on a server response. Is it possible to access vee-validate's global `errors` (ErrorBag) collection that's used as an attribute typically?

According to [this](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/451), I should be able to add to the errors object, but `this` isn't the same when I'm in my store object obviously.

For example:

```
<span id="error-message" v-if="errors.has('phone')">error message</span>
```

I'm hoping there's a way to access that `errors` collection. Is there a way I need to import `VeeValidate` to get access to what I need? Is it globally available somehow?

Comment: Pass the errors object from the component as an argument to the action.

Comment: I really liked that idea. But when I log `this.$validator.errors.items` before the action, it shows me an empty array (that's another issue) but then when I log it from inside the action itself, it's empty. Can I only pass one additional parameter to actions?

Comment: I believe both actions and mutations accept a single `payload` argument, which you can make an object to pass multiple parameters. You can also destructure them. So it would be something like `myAction({commit, state}, {errors, other}){...}`, which you would call with `dispatch("myAction", {errors: this.errors, other})`.

Comment: The *exact* syntax may be different but that's the general idea.

Comment: That worked for passing it in, but the issue I have is that updating it from the actions won't actually mean that the errors will show, unless I'm doing something wrong. If I add an error to the errorbag, I'd like it to show up on the page where I'm doing errors('phone').first() but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Here's how I'm adding it: `errors.add('phone', 'This is a cool error', 'what is this for');`

Comment: Beyond this point I would just have to play with it. [The docs](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/api.html#error-bag) indicate that what you are doing looks right in their example, *but* the parameters listed for `add` show just an error *object*. You could try with an object I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that errors raised in the action be added to the store, and accessed in the component from a computed property.

That follows the one-way-data-flow principle, and since computed's are reactive should give an opportunity for the view to update asynchronously.

Perhaps:

```
<span id="error-message" v-if="allErrors.has('phone')">error message</span>

computed: {
  allErrors() {
    return this.$validator.errors
      .concat( this.$store.state.asyncErrors )
}
```

Details need to be fleshed out.